# How do I make the manifest available during a Maven/Surefire unittest run "mvn test"?

Tags: maven-2, junit4, surefire, manifest.mf

How do I make the manifest available during a Maven/Surefire unittest run "mvn test" ?

I have an open-source project that I am converting from Ant to Maven, including its unit tests. Here's the project source repository with the Maven project:
http://github.com/znerd/logdoc

My question pertains to the primary module, called "base". This module has a unit test that tests the behaviour of the static method `getVersion()` in the class `org.znerd.logdoc.Library`. This method returns:

```
Library.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion()
```

The `getImplementationVersion()` method returns a value of a setting in the manifest file. So far, so good. I have tested this in the past and it works well, as long as the manifest is indeed available on the classpath at the path `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` (either on the file system or inside a JAR file).

Now my challenge is that the manifest file is not available when I run the unit tests:

```
mvn test
```

Surefire runs the unit tests, but my unit test fails with a mesage indicating that `Library.getVersion()` returned `null`.

When I want to check the JAR, I find that it has not even been generated. Maven/Surefire runs the unit tests against the classes, *before* the resources are added to the classpath.

Further investigation shows Surefire generates its own JAR file in a temporary directory, e.g.

```
/private/var/folders/TR/TREvj1wIHYyAcUy-xmc3UU+++TI/-Tmp-/surefirebooter7448562488934426857.jar
```

And then uses this JAR to load the Library class. This JAR does not contain the resources I stuck under `src/main/resources`. So putting a `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file also does not work.

So how do I tell Surefire to have my `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file available from the same class loader as the `Library` class.

> Note that I use Maven 2.2.0, Java 1.6.0_17 on Mac OS X 10.6.2, with JUnit 4.8.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, as you pointed you, the problem is that the `MANIFEST.MF` is generated during `package` and directly included in the final jar and all this occurs after `test`. So I guess you'll have to either:

- provide [your own MANIFEST.MF](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/manifestFile.html) (that would be available in `target/classes` before being merged during `package`). I don't know if this is an option (and if it will work).
- put and run your test from another module depending on the JAR.

Comment: Pascal, thank you very much for the answer. I tried both:

When I add a file <code>src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</code> and I run <code>mvn clean test</code> then the file does get copied to <code>target/classes/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF</code>, but it is still apparently not accessible to the unit test.

When I depend on the JAR from another module within the same project, then the JAR is not used, but the generated classes directory instead. I created <a href="http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SUREFIRE-620">issue report SUREFIRE-620</a> for this.

Comment: @Ernst Well, I didn't help but you're welcome :) I had a big doubt about the first solution but it looks like I was too much confident for the second one. Thank you for posting the Jira issue, it's an interesting case.

Comment: I did some more investigation and updated the question. I will do some more searching. Perhaps an "find-additional-class-path-here" kind-of-instruction will work.

Comment: The first solution Pascal suggested will work in theory. I have files (including Hibernate ".hbm.xml" files) in my "src/main/resources" directory which are accessible to my tests in a Maven surefire run. There must be something unexpected happening behind the scenes. I also looked at your source code and the pom.xml files all seem correctly configured. I did however notice that you are explicitely using version 2.5 of the surefire plugin and version 2.7.1 is now available on Maven Central, have you tryed using the latest version?

Comment: Also ensure you are referencing classpath files with the "classpath:/" string otherwise the classes may be trying to find the files relative to their location.