# Package.getImplementationVersion method for junit

Tags: eclipse, maven, junit, jar, manifest.mf

Is it possible to get Package.getImplementationVersion() method available for junits? I am using maven and eclipse. I tried to execute mvn war:manifest to create the manifest file, so I could verify that the Implementation Version is not null.

Currently here is my test unit which is failing:

> assertNotNull(Version.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to verify if the MANIFEST file of the war contains certain fields, a standard unit-test is too early, since the war hasn't been packaged yet.
Instead I would write a junit-test for the [maven-failsafe-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/). Now your testclass has to end with IT instead of Test so it is recognized as an integration test by the plugin.
Next, find the war-file in the target-directory and read it as a [JarFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/jar/JarFile.html), so you have direct access to the Manifest.
The rest shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Sorry for the delay but I did what you suggested and it worked! Thank you. Also I found this as a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916209/how-do-i-make-the-manifest-available-during-a-maven-surefire-unittest-run-mvn-t